# Azure Pipeline Check is any builds are running in different azure pipeline task

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

So to give you a bit of context we have a service which has been split into two different services ie one for the read and one for the write side operations. The read side is called ProductStore and the write side is called ProductCatalog. The issue were facing was down the write side as the load tests create 100 products in the write side resource web app and then they are transferred to the read side for the load test to then read x number of times. If a build is launched in the product catalog because something new was merged to master then this will cause issues in the product store pipeline if it gets run concurrently.

The question I want to ask is there a way in the ProductStore yaml file to directly query via a specified azure task or via an AzurePowershell script to check if a build is currently running in the ProductCatalog pipeline.

The second part of this would be to loop/wait until that pipeline has successfully finished before resuming the product store pipeline.

Hope this is clear as I'm not sure how to best ask this question as I'm very new to the DevOps pipelines flow but this would massively help if there was a good way of checking this sort of thing.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround , you can set [Pipeline completion trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in ProductStore pipeline.

To trigger a pipeline upon the completion of another, specify the triggering pipeline as a [pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops#resources-pipelines).

Or configure build completion triggers in the UI, choose **Triggers** from the settings menu, and navigate to the YAML pane.

[image]
[image]